# Merging RSS Feeds in Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, rss

I'm trying to merge RSS feeds using python and then play them back out to a website.  Having researched the recommended methods I've opted for the following code which is basically a straight copy of what is recommended:

```
    hit_list = ['http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/teams/cardiff-city/rss.xml','http://www1.skysports.com/feeds/11704/news.xml','http://www.cardiffcity-mad.co.uk/rssfeeds/rssfull.asp']
    # pull down all feeds
    future_calls = [Future(feedparser.parse,rss_url) for rss_url in hit_list]
    # block until they are all in
    feeds = [future_obj() for future_obj in future_calls]

    #Now that you have your feeds, extract all the entries
    entries = []
    for feed in feeds:
        entries.extend(feed["items"])

    values['feeds'] = sorted(entries, key=lambda entry: entry["updated_parsed"])
```

Later, I call the web using:

```
template = jinja_environment.get_template('TeamView.html')
self.response.out.write(template.render(values))
```

Finally, within my html page I have:

```
 {% for r in feeds.entries %}
      <a href={{r.link}} target=_blank>{{r.title}}</a>: {{r.description}}
      <br/>
 {% endfor %}
```

When I use feedparser on the feeds individually I can pass the information but when I try merging the feeds nothing shows.  I have imported feedparser and Future.

Comment: I think you're mixing up your variables. They're confusingly named, which doesn't help: 'items' becomes 'entries', and then you make values['feeds'] a list of entries, then try to reference feeds.entries? Messy.

Comment: It's a straight copy of code recommended elsewhere on stakeoverflow with the exception I changed the last statement to be values['feeds'] rather than sorted_entries.  items and entries are all part of feedparser which is virtually standardised code.  I think it should work so I've done something really dumb, but what?

Comment: Did you figure this out? If so, can you post the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer by breaking down the output.  The for loop is taking out the entries tag and holding them at  higher level so my html needs to be:

```
{% for r in feeds %}
      <a href={{r.link}} target=_blank>{{r.title}}</a>: {{r.description}}
      <br/>
{% endfor %}
```

Works perfectly now

Answer (score 0):

Your sorted() call is missing a closing paren.

Comment: My heart leapt when I read that, but in the code it is actually there; I didn't transfer it properly.